# How to remove ,00 or .00 from the back of a price?

Tags: php, string

How can I remove ,00 from the back of a price?
Example:
input1: 100.000,00
output1: 100.000

input2: 100.000.00
output2: 100.000

what I've tried is:

```
preg_replace("/[^(0-9)\.\,(0-9)]/", '', $text)
```

but it always return 100

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this pattern

```
preg_replace('/[\.,]0{2}$/', '', $text);
```

**Notes:**

- `[\.,]` - Matches single period or comma
- `0{2}` - matches the character 0 exactly two times
- `$`- assert position at the end of string

Answer (score 1):

You can use `number_format()`

```
$number = '100.000,00';
echo number_format(floatval($number), 3, '.', '');
```

Output:

```
100.000 // same output for '100.000.00'
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr to remove the last three chars.

```
substr('100.000,00', 0, -3)
```